# Identifying the *real* public keys of ring signatures

Tags: ring-signatures

Since a ring signature uses `|R-1|` decoy outputs for a ring of size `R`, is it possible to retrieve from them the real (which reveals the true wallet) `A,B` values from those stealth addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Every public key in the ring is valid as they are all stealth addresses. You cannot determine which is the real destination (which wallet receives the funds or how much).

A good explanation of stealth addresses can be found [here](https://steemit.com/monero/@luigi1111/understanding-monero-cryptography-privacy-part-2-stealth-addresses).